# Can't disable Magento Extension - Cache cleared

Tags: javascript, cache, ajax

Some of my website extension stopped working for some reason, yesterday i tried a full rollback to a day that i know it was supposed to work but still with error.

When i try to disable a `custom magento extension` .I `generally disable it by changing the active node` at the extension module `config to false`.

But this isn't working at all.

Also, if i change other things in the extension like it's name, IT WORKS!

I already clear the cache, but i am using  `redis` and `memcache`, maybe there is a problem at redis?

Answer (score 2):

i can suggest you if you have ssh access you can flush redis and memcache with respective command.

**Redis**

from shell: `redis-cli flushall`

**Memcache**

telnet your-memcached-server-ip PORT

where your-memcached-server-ip = localhost or IP

and PORT = generally uses 11211 then you will see output like

```
Trying 192.168.1.10...
Connected to cache01.nixcraft.net.in.
Escape character is ‘^]’.
```

and give `flush_all`

and close this connection by `quit`

hope this will work for you.

Comment: I just disabled redis, but still not working... I am starting to think this could be some java/ajax problem